# ttys000 /dev/fd/12:18: command not found: compdef " when starting terminal on a Mac (Ventura OSx). What could be causing this? Possible fixes?

Tags: terminal

I've just started getting the line

```
ttys000 /dev/fd/12:18: command not found: compdef
```

when I start the Mac terminal.

Do you know what might be causing it and how to fix it?

I just ran XAMPP recently after not having used it for a year or more. I also installed a new version of MySQL Workbench - 8.0, uninstalled, reinstalled an older version 5.3, and then uninstalled it.  It seems like it might have been after this that it started.
Also, when I try to update Homebrew it just hangs.

I tried this command but it didn't do anything:

```
autoload -Uz compinit
```

I have Ventura installed.

Comment: Questions about interactive shell configuration, as opposed to software development, are generally better suited to [unix.se].

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that worked for me from discussions.apple.com from user mulregex:

*For me it was the line below in the .zshrc file. For those that don't know you can find this as a hidden file ('Command' + 'Shift' + '.' to reveal) in your user directory. Remove or comment this line in a text editor or IDE of your choice.

```
# Load Angular CLI autocompletion.
source <(ng completion script)*
```

Apparently, the Angular CLI installation added the line in my case...could've been added by the MySQL Workbench installer.